# How to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $y = \frac{x\sin 3x}{1-\cos^2 3x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find the derivative w.r.t $x$ of $$y = \frac{x\sin 3x}{1-\cos^2 3x}$$

This is my answer:

$$y = \frac{x\sin 3x}{\sin^2 3x} \implies y = \frac{x}{\sin 3x}$$ Hence, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sin 3x - x \cos 3x \times 3}{\sin^2 3x}$$ $$\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sin 3x -3x\cos 3x}{\sin^2 3x}$$

Is this answer right?

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Comment: You can also use wolfram alpha to check the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, indeed ! There are also many programs, toolkits, widgets and mathematics language packs that help you check your results, such as the famous widget-site ***Wolfram Alpha*** or some other installable programs like ***Mathematica***, ***Matlab*** etc as mentioned in the comments as well.